# auto-generated code throw lots of warning in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I recently upgrade my visual studio from 2013 to 2015. now when I open my projects I see so many warning in auto generated code with code CA2235.

Here is one of the warnings:

> Warning   CA2235  Field extensionDataField is a member of type WebServiceInputTrafficFinesInquiry which is serializable but is of type System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject which is not serializable
>
> SimpayRobot    C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Projects\SimpayRobot_SVN\trunk\SimpayRobot\SimpayRobot\Service References\RahvarService\Reference.cs 22
>
> All fields that cannot be serialized directly should have the NonSerializedAttribute. Types that have the SerializableAttribute should not have fields of types that do not have the SerializableAttribute unless the fields are marked with the NonSerializedAttribute.

The project works just fine but it makes programming uncomfortable. I don't know what to do. It is auto generated code and I don't want edit it.

How can I get rid of these warnings?
One more thing: warnings are because of a soap service reference I added to the project.

***UPDATE:***
I don't want to suppress the warning! Why should I do it? I want solve the problem.

Here is line 22:(It is part of the auto generated code.)

```
[System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;
```

Comment: you can surpress specific warnings for your project: Go to **Your Project** -> Preferences -> Build Tab and enter the Warning in the "Surpress Warnings"-TextBox.

Comment: Thanks. but i don't want to suppress the warning! why should i do it? i want solve the problem.

Comment: well, ok. in this case, have a deeper look at the warning. It tells you that a Field is (probably implicitly) marked as serializable, while its type is not serializable. It tells you to add `[NonSerialized]` to that filed. if you post the code around Reference.cs line 22 (the whole class if its not to long) I can show you how that would look like.

Comment: Well you can either edit the code or suppress the warnings, or downgrade back to 2013.

Comment: I don't know the reason, but can you try following? re-generate server reference or remove System.Runtime.Serialization reference and add it back.It looks like extensionDataField is marked as NonSerialized but VS 2015 can't recognize it. Can you create another VS 2015 project and copy generated code to verify it again?

Comment: done. same result. (completely remove the reference and i add it again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when I started checking my source code with FxCops. Starting my investigation with this post it seems that the CA2235 warnings in reference.cs (automatically generated by WCF-services) are classified as an issue that will be solved in Visual Studio Update 3 (see this link https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3898 for further information)

Regards
JRB

Answer (score 0):

Type of your field/property `ExtensionDataObject`  is not serializable, but it's part of the class which is marked as `serializable`.

You should either mark your `ExtensionDataObject` as `Serializable`, or decorate with with `NonSerializedAttribute` .

For an example if you try to store your object in a session, it will not be able to serialize all of it's properties, and it could throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Have a deeper look at the warning. It tells you that a Field is (probably implicitly) marked as serializable, while its type is not serializable. It tells you to add [NonSerialized] to that filed.

You can work this out like that (im just guessing what your code might look like):

```
[Serializable]
public class WebServiceInputTrafficFinesInquiry 
{
    // ...

    [NonSerialized]
    ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    // ...
}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182349.aspx for more information.

Comment: thank you dear @nozzlemen. but i have two questions: 1- why auto generate code throw a warring? 2- is it because of web service source code? i mean should i inform the web service developer to fix the code?

Comment: if the developer of web service is author of those classes, then he is the one who should fix it. There is nothing wrong wit the code, it just warns that it could cause problems in some scenarios.

Comment: @Dan have a look at the link. I suggest to try to create an instance of `WebServiceInputTrafficFinesInquiry` manually and then try to serialize it. If  the developer did not declare a separate SerializationSurrogate which would allow for that type to be serialized, this should throw an `SerializationException`. In this case, it would be a good idea to tell the author of that class to fix it.

Comment: @nozzleman thank you so much. but the web service works just fine. i consume the same web service rest full and by reference for about the year. i haven't seen any exception in serialization!!

Comment: serialization will break if you try to serialize object to a session and session state is set to SQL Mode

Comment: Thank you @Robert. it means the web service has a bug?

Comment: it could lead to a problem if you try to serialize object in some scenarios. Models should be properly marked with attributes, and warning messages should disappear. 
If warning messages do not disturb you, you do not have option to change given models, and you need to serialize it, you can always recreate models on your own, preform a deep copy and serialize your own model.